# Spring webflux data in ReactJs UI

Tags: reactjs, server-sent-events, spring-webflux

I am playing around with spring webflux. I have created a project which would listen on a mongo capped collection and return the flux of data as and when it comes.
I am using `@Tailable`in my repository method.

My controller looks like this

```
@GetMapping("/findall")
  public Flux<Product>> findAll() {
    return productRepository.findAllProducts().;
 }
```

This is working perfectly fine. I tested this by addind a `doOnNext(...)`, Whenever there is a new item added to my capped collection, consumer inside the doOnNext is executed.

Now I want this to be displayed on the browser. And I wanted to do with ReactJs(I am completely new to frontend).

So far, I couldn't find any way to display the flux data in browser. What are the options by which I can achieve this.

I tried SSE(Server Sent Event) like this

```
 componentDidMount() {
   this.eventSource = new EventSource('http://localhost:8080/findall');
   this.eventSource.addEventListener('product', (data) => {
            let json = JSON.parse(data.data)
            this.state.products.push(json.name)
            this.setState ( {
                products : this.state.products
            })
        });
 }
```

This works perfectly fine, but for this to work, I had to change my server side code like this

```
 @GetMapping("/findall")
  public Flux<ServerSentEvent<Product>> findAll() {
    return productRepository.findAllProducts().map(data -> ServerSentEvent.<Product>builder().event("product").data(data).build());
  }
```

This, in my opinion is a bit tightly coupled because, UI should know the event type('product') to listen to.

Is there any other way to handle stream of events from UI side(particularly with `reactjs`) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have to change your controller in order to stream data to the browser. The following code snippet should work:

```
@GetMapping(path="/findall", produces=MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public Flux<Product>> findAll() {
    return productRepository.findAllProducts();
}
```

You can see this feature being used in [this workshop](https://bclozel.github.io/webflux-workshop/) and [this sample app](https://github.com/snicoll-demos/smart-meter) if you'd like to see a complete working examples.

Comment: Thanks @Brian. That works fine.  Just a follow up question. In that case, when would I use SSE on the server side?

Comment: For server to server communication, `MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON` is a better choice.

Comment: Cheers, ya makes sense. This whole process works.(i.e. from a capped collection to server and then to browser), But on my server side, i keep seeing this exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response`. I can write a separate question for it,